# Reference object from environment without assignment

Tags: r, memory-management

I have a function that looks like this:

```
sampleFcn <- function(c1, c2) {
  chars <- get('chars', envir=.GlobalEnv)
  if (c1 %in% chars) { 
    array[c1,1] <<- array[c1,1] + 1
    if (c2 %in% chars)  bigM[c1,c2] <<- bigM[c1,c2] + 1
  }
}
```

This will be applied across a large data set. As it is now, it works but it takes very long to apply, and I'm guessing that's mostly because of the second line, where I'm constantly assigning, to a new variable, a large vector (chars). My question is, how do I call the global variable 'chars' without having to constantly use new memory to assign it with the 'get' function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would rethink your assumptions about where your code is inefficient:

```
library(pryr)
x <- matrix(1:1e6,10)
> object_size(x)
4 MB

track_x <- track_copy(x)

foo <- function(){
    r1 <- mem_change(s <- get("x",.GlobalEnv))
    r2 <- mem_change(2 %in% s)
    list(r1,r2)
}

> foo() #No noticeable memory use
[[1]]
14 kB

[[2]]
1.74 kB


> track_x()
# Nothing changed

> mem_changed(x[1,1] <- x[1,1]+1)
4MB #Increased by 4MB

> track_x()
x copied #Because it copied
```

Comment: Thanks! So every time I increment a matrix element by 1, the whole matrix is reassigned to memory? Do you know a way around that?

Comment: @Bridgeburners How R decides when it needs to create a copy and when it operates by reference is complicated. So I'd shy away from saying that R will copy a matrix _every_ time you increment a single value. But modifying objects with `<-` will typically be a source of copying. I would look into the **data.table** package which allows for the creation and modification of columns by reference.